# Conditional probability with false positives

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

"A disease effects 1/1000 newborns and shortly after birth a baby is
screened for this disease using a cheap test that has a 2% false
positive rate (the test has no false negatives). If the baby tests
positive, what is the chance it has the disease?"

I've got P(disease|positive)=P(d^p)/P(p)=(1/1000)/(1/1000+2/100*999/1000)=1/(20 + 49/50)

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. Alternatively, you could have used Bayes's theorem:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{sick}\,|\,\text{pos})=\frac{\mathbb{P}(\text{pos}\,|\,\text{sick})\times\mathbb{P}(\text{sick})}{\mathbb{P}(\text{pos}\,|\,\text{sick})\times\mathbb{P}(\text{sick})+\mathbb{P}(\text{pos}\,|\,\text{healthy})\times\mathbb{P}(\text{healthy})}.
\end{align*}

Now we know that $\mathbb{P}(\text{sick})=1/1000$ and $\mathbb{P}(\text{healthy})=999/1000$. Also, $\mathbb{P}(\text{pos}\,|\,\text{sick})=1$ (since there are no false negatives: whoever is sick will test positive) and $\mathbb{P}(\text{pos}\,|\,\text{healthy})=2/100$ (the rate of false positives).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct, but be careful.

The reasoning above is correct and works nicely because the false negative rate is 0, so you get that P(d^p) = P(d) = 1/1000. Otherwise, you would need to use Bayes' Formula:

P(d|p) = P(p|d)P(d)/P(p)